# Xcode semantic issue refdefenition or previously defined code

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm new to all of this. I'm trying to learn C++ on Xcode's IDE.

For experimentation, I made a variable `slices = 6`. I made another variable `kids = slices`.

This was to prove to myself that this copies the value of slices to kids, unlike in Python where if I have `x=10` and `y=x` then when I make `y=8` then `x=8` also, but in C++, saying `slices = 6`, `kids = slices`, then later saying `slices = 10` will mean that kids will still equals `6`.

Writing for a second time `slices = <anything I put here>` issued an error saying *Redefinition of slices* not allowing me to do it.

I know this was put there following the DRY principle to not redo a piece of code or change it without realising, but how can I overcome this simple issue?

The code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World. I think you got this!\n";
  int slices = 6;
  int kids = slices;
  int slices = 100;
  std::cout << kids;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are describing.

Comment: And the _exact_ code.

Comment: Hello cigien and gnasher729. The code I used is here.                                   #include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World. I think you got this!\n" ;
    int slices = 6;
    int kids = slices;
    int slices = 100;
    std:: cout << kids;
    return 0;

} (I realised my error as I tried to redefine int slices previously with int slices again later on. Just saying slices = 100; instead works. Why is that?) Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:
`int slices = 100;`

Remove `int` and the compile error goes away because you are attempting to declare two variables called `slices`.

It is also true that the variables `kids` and `slices` still act independently of each other. When you assign `slices` to `kids`, you are assigning the *value* of `slices`, not `slices` itself.

You are likely thinking of pointers/references. That's a whole other bag of worms.